Exported image have blue background when rendered within rayshader
I am trying to export the plot_3D output for rayshader using render_highquality as following:
veg_mat |>
  height_shade(texture = "white") |>
  add_overlay(x, alphalayer = 1) |>
  plot_3d(
    veg_mat,
    baseshape = "circle",
    solid = TRUE,
    zscale = 1,
    zoom = 0.8,
    phi = 45,
    theta = 0,
    windowsize = 800,
    background = "white"
  )

render_highquality(
  filename = "Veg_x.png",
  preview = FALSE,
  parallel = TRUE,
  light = FALSE,
  width = 2000,
  height = 1200,
  samples = 256,
  sample_method = "sobol_blue"
)

The code works nicely and gives high resolution output image (against snapshots), but there is this sky blue background which is unwanted. Where does it come from and how do I remove it?


What background colour do you want, or do you want a file with a transparent background?

We can't run this code without veg_mat and x - can you make an example using the sample data in the package?

Well I don't want any color at all, so yes transparent would be good.  Yes, please find here attached the sample data with code refined and used : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DB_YcHalMF1UdOdwRcAwtXoQJHCcge8N/view?usp=sharing

How do you make veg_mat from that tiff? The docs for height_shade want a 2d matrix.

Using rayshader::raster_to_matrix(veg_rast). Tutorial followed is here -https://www.rayshader.com/

then I get Error: object 'x' not found because of line 3 in your first code block, at add_overlay(x,....).

So sorry the drive link was not from the folder with all files - Please find everything here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pyDYJ9VRkxllB97BKit2iNKIUopkeafB?usp=sharing

Hello, can someone help me in this? I am still looking for the solution.

I've been away for a week, plus it was crashing my R session on my other laptop, and takes about 20 minutes to run at the resolution of your example. I cut it down to 200x120 to get a workable example for experimenting. Results below.

Add
backgroundhigh="#FFFFFF",
backgroundlow="#FFFFFF",

to your render_highquality(...) call arguments to get a white background.
The render_highquality function passes extra arguments via ...  to render_scene, so read the help for render_scene for more info.
There is a transparent_background option but I couldn't get a true opacity to work using it.

Thank you very much. It worked.
